# bash: print to file or stdout if file not given

Tags: bash, stdout

**How can I emulate the behavior "print to stdout if output file not given" in my own BASH script?**

I want to emulate the behavior of, e.g. unix utility `sort`:

```
sort  input   
# prints to stdout

sort  -o out  input
# prints to file "out".  does not print to stdout.
```

Sadly, the only thing I came up with is, at the very end of my BASH script:

```
if [ ! -z "$OUT" ]; then
    some | commands > $OUT
else
    some | commands 
    # prints to stdout
fi
```

Comment: Just check argument `$` to your script. If it is present then write to it otherwise write to stdout

Answer (score 3):

If your objection is to the repetition of the commands, you can use `/dev/stdout` as the file name in a redirection if no other file name is given.

```
output=${OUT:-/dev/stdout}
some | commands > "$output"
```

Comment: does this have to be the last line of the script?  can there be commands after this (e.g. remove temporary files.  print something to stderr)

Comment: It can be used anywhere. `/dev/stdout` is just a special name that `bash` recognizes as a synonym for standard output when used with a redirection operator, whether or not `/dev/stdout` actually exists in your file system.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to redirect all the output inside your shell script to a log file if "-o " is present or else print to stdout. Try the below script for it,

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTIND=1
LOG_FILE=""
while getopts "o:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    o)  LOG_FILE=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
[ ! -z $LOG_FILE ] && exec >$LOG_FILE

echo "This line will be inside log file if -o <filename> is given"
```

If you name the above script as "parse.sh", you should use

```
./parse.sh -o output.txt #This will store all logs/echos inside "output.txt"
./parse.sh #This will print all the logs/echos to stdout
```

You can even avoid using getopts if your not using more then one input arguments by directly accessing "$1"